# is sharding based on the first char of username an example of consistent hashing?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, partitioning, sharding

is sharding based on firstchar of user's name an example of consistent hashing?

To be sure, if i shard my database depending on the char-length of the user's name, is it Consistent hashing in the sense that addition or removal of one slot does not change the mapping of keys to slots?

(I know it is definitely not the most efficient way to shard data, but what i'm interested in is by the definition of consistent hashing, is that way of sharding considered consistent?)

Comment: I am not an expert in the area, but I don't know if sharding by first letter of username is going to give you effective distribution. You won't have too many x, q or z (though admittedly probably a higher percentage than if we were talking about given names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's consistent but it is not much of a hash

run a test sharding on actual data (using group by and count) and you will see how effective it is

my guess would be that it would be very uneven